# Find ArrayList for no sequence data in Java

Tags: logic

I need to get arrayList of postalCodes by Reagion IDs, but my region id's are not in provided sequence and zip codes must be associates with mentioned region id. (This data is an small example, I have csv file in with thousands of zip Code)
Please help me out to write a correct logic for it in Java.

```
Zip Codes V/s Region Ids = {"71854 , 612" ; "71865, 612"; "88008, 765"; "88021, 765" ; "88252 , 612"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this of two ways.

- first declare a structure that contain the two values required and then fill an array with the values, as show in the example.

  struct Data{

  ```
  int zip_code, region_id;

  Data() {}

  Data(int z, int r) {

      zip_code = z;

      region_id = r;

  }
  ```

  };

  ## define MAX 100

  Data my_list[MAXN];
- second declare declare two parallel arrays and fill these with the data requiered

  ## define MAX 100

  int zip_code[MAX] = {71854, 71865, 88008, 88021, 88252};

  int region_id[MAX] = {612, 612, 765, 765, 612};